# required: net.liftweb.util.CanBind [java.lang.String]

Tags: scala, lift

I am migrating this code to version 2.5

https://github.com/dpp/simply_lift/blob/master/samples/shopwithme/

When compiling the project

sends me an error like the following:

```
[error] /lift/shopwithme/src/main/scala/code/comet/CometCart.scala:40: type mismatch;
[error] found: scala.xml.NodeSeq
[error] required: net.liftweb.util.CanBind [java.lang.String]
[error] = val theTR ("tr ^^" #> "**") (ns)
[error] 

                                      ^
```

https://github.com/dpp/simply_lift/blob/master/samples/shopwithme/src/main/scala/code/comet/CometCart.scala

Can someone help me with this please

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you forgot the equation`=` sign?.. This should still work in recent Lift releases (2.6, 3.0-SNAPSHOT):  `("div" #> "hello")(ns: NodeSeq)`

Answer (score 0):

It takes an implicit canBind. Either first put the CssSel in a val, and then use function application on it:

```
val tmp = "tr ^^" #> "**"
val theTR = tmp(ns)
```

or else write `apply` explicitly:

```
val theTR = "tr ^^" #> "**" apply ns
```